# MS Access Search Form for Large database

Tags: ms-access, search, vba

I'm building a database that will be accommodating a large number of records, so I want a search function that is easiest on the server. I am using the following code but I know it isn't sustainable for a larger database. It's looking at the search box and running a query to narrow the search results:

```
Private Sub SearchFor_Change()
'Create a string (text) variable
Dim vSearchString As String

'Populate the string variable with the text entered in the Text Box SearchFor
vSearchString = SearchFor.Text

'Pass the value contained in the string variable to the hidden text box SrchText,
'that is used as the sear4ch criteria for the Query QRY_SearchAll
SrchText.Value = vSearchString

'Requery the List Box to show the latest results for the text entered in Text Box
'SearchFor
Me.SearchResults.Requery


'Tests for a trailing space and exits the sub routine at this point
'so as to preserve the trailing space, which would be lost if focus was shifted from   
'Text Box SearchFor
 If Len(Me.SrchText) <> 0 And InStr(Len(SrchText), SrchText, " ", vbTextCompare) Then
 'Set the focus on the first item in the list box
 Me.SearchResults = Me.SearchResults.ItemData(1)
 Me.SearchResults.SetFocus
 'Requery the form to refresh the content of any unbound text box that might be feeding 
 'off the record source of  the List Box
 DoCmd.Requery
 'Returns the cursor to the the end of the text in Text Box SearchFor,
 'and restores trailing space lost when focus is shifted to the list box
  Me.SearchFor = vSearchString
  Me.SearchFor.SetFocus
  Me.SearchFor.SelStart = Me.SearchFor.SelLength

  Exit Sub
  End If
  'Set the focus on the first item in the list box
   Me.SearchResults = Me.SearchResults.ItemData(1)
   Me.SearchResults.SetFocus

   'Requery the form to refresh the content of any unbound text box that might be 
   'feeding off the record source of  the List Box
  DoCmd.Requery

'Returns the cursor to the the end of the text in Text Box SearchFor
 Me.SearchFor.SetFocus

If Not IsNull(Len(Me.SearchFor)) Then
Me.SearchFor.SelStart = Len(Me.SearchFor)
End If
```

Ideally I want a form that has several search fields, and one 'find' button that runs the queries to return the results in a list box.

I'm also not sure how to set it up so that when the user double clicks on a selection from the search results, the selected record is opened in a form in edit mode.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you've asked two questions in one post. I recommend you take out the second question regarding opening the selection in edit mode on double click.

As best as I can understand, you're concerned about the performance of your current code as well as the lack of features or flexibility it offers.

Regarding performance:

- Don't use the change method to perform the filter. If you really do want to use the change method, use it only to set a timer interval to something like 500 (ms) and then perform the filter on the Timer event. This was the filter won't occur until after the user has stopped typing for a half second.
- Avoid "fuzzy" searches (use of asterisk/percent in text fields). It doesn't look like you're using them now. While fuzzy searches usually make software more user friendly, they make it less user friendly when they cause a significant hit on the performance.
- When working with large amounts of data, most performance gains come from carefully restructuring the way your application works, by upgrading to SQL Server, and by upgrading your server and network to better hardware. You can only improve about so much when using a JET/ACE backend database container. SQL Server with ADO and ODBC linked tables both offer some advantages over DAO with JET/ACE. ODBC linked tables offer lazy loading while ADO offers things like disconnected recordsets which can be filtered without an additional call back to the server (there are limitations to this).
- As already mentioned above, you might need to carefully rethink how your application works and how it is designed. It's better to try to limit the amount of complicated queries that are needed and the amount of text-based searching that is allowed/required. Use more lookup/reference tables. Instead of storing thinks like categories as text, consider storing them as a Long Number CategoryID instead. Queries on indexed numeric fields usually perform better than queries on text-based fields, especially if you are using LIKE with asterisks in your query.

As far as the rest of your question (flexibility and features), consider creating a procedure that builds a criteria/where statement for you based on the values of multiple controls. In a situation such as yours my code would look something like this (below). Notice that I did use asterisk (fuzzy search) in my Description search/filter. If it performs poorly you'll need to consider taking that out and allowing the user to put their own asterisks in instead.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Call SetRowSource
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_AfterUpdate()
    Call SetRowSource
End Sub

Private Sub cboCategoryID_AfterUpdate()
    Call SetRowSource
End Sub

Private Sub txtBrand_AfterUpdate()
    Call SetRowSource
End Sub

Private Sub SetRowSource()
    Dim sSQL as String
    sSQL = "SELECT ItemID, Description, Brand FROM tblItems "
    sSQL = sSQL & GetWhere
    Me.lstSearchResults.RowSource = sSQL
End Sub

Private Function GetWhere() as String
    Dim sWhere as String
    If Nz(Me.cboCategoryID, 0) <> 0 Then
        sWhere = sWhere & "CategoryID = " & Me.cboCategoryID & " AND "
    End If
    If Nz(Me.txtSearch, "") <> "" Then
        sWhere = sWhere & "Description LIKE '*" & Replace(Me.txtSearch, "'", "''") & "*' AND "
    End If
    If Nz(Me.txtBrand, "") <> "" Then
        sWhere = sWhere & "Brand = '" & Replace(Me.txtBrand, "'", "''") & "' AND "
    End If
    If sWhere <> "" Then
        sWhere = Left(sWhere, Len(sWhere)-5)
        GetWhere = "WHERE " & sWhere
    End If
End Function
```

I think I might be a little bit odd in the Access community but I generally do not allow my controls to reference other controls. In your case the RowSource in your listbox references the controls of the form it's located on. For a variety of reasons, I prefer to build my SQL statements in VBA code, particularly when they are subject to change/filtering. Another thing you might consider doing is using a Datasheet form instead of a listbox. You can set the form's RecordSource and just apply your WHERE statement to the form's Filter property then. Datasheet forms are more flexible for the user as they can resize columns and do sorting without any help from you the programmer. You can always lock the controls so they can't do any editing. When I use datasheets this way I think use the DoubleClick event to allow them to open the record, which is arguably less user friendly then using the single click on a listbox.

Comment: Thanks, HK1. This was very helpful - I'm working on adopting your code suggestions to my own.